# Making SELECT SQL Queries in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been searching everywhere on Google but for no good. I am working on ASP.NET MVC website and the main goal of the website is to view and manipulate data from an already existing (huge) database in SQL Server.
I want to view all the data on the left side of the screen, and have some 'filters' on the other side, which on selected make changes on the table, that is different `SELECT` statements with `WHERE` conditions. I also want these filters to change data on specific rows. For example, I select a row of the database, I see those details on the filters and change them. These will be `UPDATE` statements.
 I wanted to give this detailed context so my future motives are clear and I won't have to go back to scratch.

I have tried a number of tutorials but none of them were good enough to help me with my issues. I was able to display my data with `@Html.ActionLink("List of students", "Index", "Students")` as shown in Microsoft Docs. This can help me edit, delete and create data but I cannot filter my desired results and have little control over it.

This is a how my filters and editing of data should look:

https://ibb.co/71R12Zk

[image]

Comment: www.pluralsight.com has some pretty good mvc tutorials. you should check them out

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a web framework, not a data access library. That's the job of ADO.NET or ORMs like Entity Framework. The documentation for ASP.NET MVC though contains multiple examples and tutorials that show how you can read data from a database using Entity Framework

Comment: The [Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/) tutorial shows how to read, display and update data in an MVC application. [Create a web app with ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-3.0) shows how to create a simple ASP.NET Core web application that reads from a database

Comment: An ActionLink makes a simple GET request to the server, via a hyperlink. Whilst it is possible to add parameters to a GET request, if you have as many filters as shown in your screenshot, you really would be better with a form containing a submit button (note _button_, not _link_) which generates a POST request to the server. In the targeted action method you should accept a ViewModel object as the parameter, which the submitted data can be bound to. You can then use this data as the parameters for your query.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is on the money with the suggested tutorial, but I suggest using the [database first tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/) instead as it more closely matches your case.